# Running Pianobar on a headless Ubuntu 18.04 server (without X11) with Alsa/Pulseaudio and streaming audio over SSH to a Mac laptop

Tags: pulseaudio

There seem to be a vast amount of articles/posts on setting up Pulseaudio and SSH but I don't know if I've seen any in regards to [pianobar](https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar).

**My scenario:**
I am running a headless Ubuntu 18.04 server WITHOUT X11.  I would like to ssh to it from my laptop and run the pianobar app so the sound comes out of my laptop.

**What I have working:**

- On the Ubuntu server I have installed Alsa and all its tools
- On the Ubuntu server I have installed pianobar
- When I physically sit at the Ubuntu server, login, and run pianobar I get sound

**What I have attempted:**

- I installed Pulseaudio and configured the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file as instructed in a lot of the google info I find.  The most important part seems to be:

`load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1`

**My problem:**
When I ssh into the server from my Mac and run pianobar the sound is still coming out of the server

I have tried a lot of variations with my ssh connection.  I understand I'm supposed to be forwarding a port of some sort but I dont know if I have even setup the server right.

Docs I have used to troubleshoot:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/28176/how-do-i-run-pulseaudio-in-a-headless-server-installation?rq=1
https://github.com/cladmi/systemd_pulseaudio_al
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/28176/how-do-i-run-pulseaudio-in-a-headless-server-installation
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939144/playing-audio-stops-in-unity-when-i-switch-user/939338#939338

Comment: I found a slight work-around.  I found an article where someone uses a go script to setup a SOCK proxy on his MAC.

<https://www.stevenirby.me/2016/04/11/use-pandora-on-the-commandline-with-pianobar-and-ssh-proxy/>

I would still like to know how to get it working as stated in the original question.